# WideCharToMultiByte doesn't work in Wine

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi, wine

I'm trying to use WideCharToMultiByte in order to convert std::wstring to utf8 std::string. Here is my code:

```
const std::wstring & utf16("lorem ipsum"); // input

if (utf16.empty()) {
    return "";
}
cout << "wstring -> string, input: , size: " << utf16.size() << endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i < utf16.size(); ++i) {
    cout << i << ": " << static_cast<int>(utf16[i]) << endl;
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < utf16.size(); ++i) {
    wcout << static_cast<wchar_t>(utf16[i]);
}
cout << endl;
std::string res;
int required_size = 0;
if ((required_size = WideCharToMultiByte(
    CP_UTF8,
    0,
    utf16.c_str(),
    utf16.size(),
    nullptr,
    0,
    nullptr,
    nullptr
)) == 0) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("Cannot convert.");
}
cout << "required size: " << required_size << endl;
res.resize(required_size);
if (WideCharToMultiByte(
    CP_UTF8,
    0,
    utf16.c_str(),
    utf16.size(),
    &res[0],
    res.size(),
    nullptr,
    nullptr
) == 0) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("Cannot convert.");
}
cout << "Result: " << res << ", size: " << res.size() << endl;
for (size_t i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i) {
    cout << i << ": " << (int)static_cast<uint8_t>(res[i]) << endl;
}
exit(1);
return res;
```

It runs OK, no exceptions, no error. Only the result is wrong. Here is output from running the code:

```
wstring -> string, input: , size: 11
0: 108
1: 111
2: 114
3: 101
4: 109
5: 32
6: 105
7: 112
8: 115
9: 117
10: 109
lorem ipsum
required size: 11
Result: lorem , size: 11
0: 108
1: 0
2: 111
3: 0
4: 114
5: 0
6: 101
7: 0
8: 109
9: 0
10: 32
```

I don't understand why are there the null bytes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What compiler/standard library are you using? I cannot reproduce with VC++ 2015 Update 1, and instead get the desired output. In any case, since you have this tagged `c++11`, the proper approach is to use [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16).

Comment: wineg++. So the code is correct in you opinion and it does work in VC 2015? Maybe I should submit bug report to the wine people then

Comment: Indeed, the code looks correct (other than initialization of `utf16`, which should use a wide literal) and works on Windows-proper. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn ok, thanks a lot for checking :)

Comment: [Works here, too](http://rextester.com/WXE81814)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>**Summarizing from comments:**</sub>

Your code is correct as far as the `WideCharToMultiByte` logic and arguments go; the only actual problem is the initialization of `utf16`, which needs to be initialized with a wide literal. The code gives the expected results with both VC++ 2015 RTM and Update 1, so this is a bug in the `WideCharToMultiByte` emulation layer you're using.

That said, for C++11 onwards, there is a portable solution you should prefer when possible: [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) in conjunction with [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16)

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iostream>

std::string test(std::wstring const& utf16)
{
    std::wcout << L"wstring -> string, input: " << utf16 << L", size: " << utf16.size() << L'\n';
    for (std::size_t i{}; i != utf16.size(); ++i)
        std::wcout << i << L": " << static_cast<int>(utf16[i]) << L'\n';
    for (std::size_t i{}; i != utf16.size(); ++i)
        std::wcout << utf16[i];
    std::wcout << L'\n';

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> cvt;
    std::string res = cvt.to_bytes(utf16);
    std::wcout << L"Result: " << res.c_str() << L", size: " << res.size() << L'\n';
    for (std::size_t i{}; i != res.size(); ++i)
        std::wcout << i << L": " << static_cast<int>(res[i]) << L'\n';
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    test(L"lorem ipsum");
}
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fa54a7aa77a4b68)</kbd>